# I need to open an image with Microsoft Paint

Tags: winapi

As the title says. I'm looking for an easy way to open an image (.jpg if it matters) with Microsoft Paint by using Windows API and the image's file path. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `CreateProcess` to run `mspaint.exe` with the filename of the image on the command line.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I've just figured out how stupid I am. Thanks.

Comment: What's easy for one person may be hard for another. So perhaps it would be better not to include that.

Comment: Does it HAVE to be MSPaint specifically? What if the user has another image editor installed and would like to use that instead? `ShellExecute()` would be better than `CreateProcess()` for running the user's default editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CreateProcess as @Jonathan Potter mentioned in the comments or you can use [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea).

```
ShellExecute(nullptr, "open", "mspaint.exe", "YourImage.jpg", nullptr, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

If as @Remy Lebeau mentions, you want the user registered default application to open the image rather than force `mspaint.exe` you can just pass the image name to `ShellExecute`

```
ShellExecute(nullptr, "open", "YoutImage.jpg", nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```